# bash verbose string comparison slashes

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I am comparing two strings in a bash script as follows:

```
x="hello"
y="hello"

if [[ "$x" != "$y" ]]; then
    echo "different"
else
    echo "same"
fi
```

This comparison works. When I execute the script with `-x`, the comparison still works, but it shows the output

```
+ x=hello
+ y=hello
+ [[ -n hello ]]
+ [[ hello != \h\e\l\l\o ]]
+ echo same
```

I'm curious why the right side of the string shows as`\h\e\l\l\o` and not `hello`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple explanation is for the same reason that the left-hand side doesn't have quotes around it.

`-x` is showing you an equivalent but not exact representation of what it ran. The right-hand side of `=` and `!=` in `[[ ... ]]` is matched as a pattern.

From the manual:

> When the  == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern Matching. .... Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.

The `-x` output, for some reason, chooses to use escaping instead quoting to disable pattern matching there.

Comment: thanks alot , I had a huge script and which has around 2000+ lines of output wile running though sh -x and I saw same thing happening there. but look likes its correct. am relived

Answer (score 0):

When using `=`, `==`, and `!=` in `[[`, the right-side string can contain globs (`*`, `?`, etc.).

The backslashes in your example aren't necessary, though they don't hurt. They are needed if the right-side string contains a possible wildcard character. For example:

```
$ set -x
$ [[ hi == 'hi*' ]]; echo $?
+ [[ hi == \h\i\* ]]
+ echo 1
1
$ [[ hi == hi* ]]; echo $?
+ [[ hi == hi* ]]
+ echo 0
0
```

Comment: I didn't actually pt the backslashes in there, I was wondering why they were showing up in the verbose output.